Tax changes after NY to NJ change in company location
Currently I work for company in NYC, but I live in NJ. so I pay NY tax as well.
My company has office in NJ as well now. I have option to select company office of NYC or NJ as my work location now. If I choose NJ location, will I save anything on taxes. My compensation is going to remain same whether I choose NYC or NJ office.

Where are you physically when you perform work? Will you change the location where you will be when you perform work?

i have option to change location from NYC to NJ to perform work.
